# Odd behavior UIActionSheet + UITableView: rows disappear

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, uitableview, uiactionsheet

I've a UITableView with some static cells in it. One of them shows a UIActionSheet when touched. Here goes the code for it:

viewDidLoad: initialize controls.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self initializeControls];
}
```

initializeControls: add gesture recognizer to the label within the cell in order to show the UIActionSheet.

```
- (void)initializeControls {
    [...]

    // Places Label
    self.placeNamesLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    tapGesture = \
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didPlaceNamesLabelWithGesture:)];
    [self.placeNamesLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    tapGesture = nil;

    [...]
}
```

didPlaceNamesLabelWithGesture: initialize UIActionSheet, add a UITableView from StoryBoard and a Close button.

```
- (void)didPlaceNamesLabelWithGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
{
    // Show UITableView in UIActionView for selecting Place objects.
    placesActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                      delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                        destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [placesActionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

    CGRect tableFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    AddArticlesPlacesViewController *placesView = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlacesForArticle"];
    placesView.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    placesView.view.frame = tableFrame;
    [placesActionSheet addSubview:placesView.view];
    placesView = nil;

    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Close"]];
    closeButton.momentary = YES;
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissPlacesActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [placesActionSheet addSubview:closeButton];
    closeButton = nil;

    [placesActionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];

    [placesActionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
}
```

dismissPlacesActionSheet: close UIActionSheet.

```
-(void)dismissPlacesActionSheet:(id)sender {
    [placesActionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; }
```

Everything works and the UITableView populates fine from Core Data. So where is the problem? The point is that when any row is tapped, the entire table gets empty (I can't post images yet, sorry).

I've tried to add a new custom row with a button that fires a push segue to the AddArticlesPlacesViewController; this works fine and the behavior is as expected. So the problem is between UIActionSheet and UITableView.

Here are the interfaces for both view controllers:

Main.

```
@interface AddArticleViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, [...]>

[...]

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *placeNamesLabel;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

[...]

@end
```

Secondary.

```
@interface AddArticlesPlacesViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end
```

I'm stuck. What am I doing wrong?

Regards.

Pedro Ventura.

Comment: Is it because the placesView managed object context and the placesView = nil?

Comment: @verbumdei: I think it isn't, the UITableView is showing data from Core Data in both solutions (inside and outside UIActionSheet).

Answer (score 0):

you can use tableview's delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

        NSLog(@"indexpath-->%d",indexPath.row);
        if (indexPath.row==0 || indexPath.row == 2 ) 
        {

            NSLog(@"row %d",indexPath.row);

        }

        if (indexPath.row==1)
     {

            actionsheet=[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sample" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
               [actionsheet showInView:self.view];

        }
    }
```

And you can use UIActionsheetDelegate's method for Selected Button:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {

         NSLog(@"index==>%d",buttonIndex);
           NSLog(@"cancel");
    }
```

Comment: I did it and this event is not fired when in UIActionSheet. - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Selected row %@", indexPath);
}

Comment: shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath, didSelectRowAtIndexPath and didSelectRowAtIndexPath are not being called when using the UIActionSheet; but yes these other ones: numberOfSectionsInTableView, sectionIndexTitlesForTableView, numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexPath.